# Min distance for markers in CartoCSS

Tags: markers, cartocss

I used shields in CartoCss to show the subway stations on my map. When I started to develop the map for mobile devices, I noticed that svg images in shields were destorted hugely and I decided to use markers instead of shields.
But then I found that I can`t set min-distance between markers rather than for shields. Before I could draw just one sign of subway entrance with label by setting min-distance between shields. But now markers draw each entrance with label and I have several similar images with labels for one station.

Is it possible to set min-distance for markers somehow? Or maybe there are other ways how to show just one station?[image]

Answer (score 1):

If this issue applies only to the backend, I would suggest you (assuming that you're running on the Postgis) to use [ST_PointOnSurface](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_PointOnSurface.html) function. This function provides the center points for a set of features in a little bit more intelligent way than a well-known [ST_Centroid](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Centroid.html).

You could just make a distinct layer that contain center points for the subway stations and show them at the selected zoom levels.

Have no idea how to implement the same trick in CartoCSS. HTH